# Group music/audio/ambience for Roll20

Tags: dnd-5e, online-roleplaying, tool-recommendation, roll20

So, I don't really like Roll20's audio system and it doesn't really align with the way I DM. I'm looking for a 3rd party application my group can all download while on the Discord call where I can cycle through music/audio without the use of Roll20. Some sort of an application where I the DM have control over what they hear and can play tracks that I upload(or similar) to the application so that they can hear. I have tried the discord bots(they're bad) so I'm really wondering if anyone has some miracle working software that would cater to the needs of my party..

Comment: I totally understand how many folks who do face to face are trying to transition to virtual, but many of these questions are really opinion-based and don't really fit our format here. When you have enough rep, you can join our very own [chat] where folks can help, or you may do better on a forum.

Comment: And if you don't know of any good forums to go to, we have a curated list [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137).

Comment: Thanks for at least guiding me to the right place! @NautArch

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I went through similar problems as you, and figured out a satisfactory way to stream music to my players. Meet me in [chat] to discuss more.